# Flutter : Cached Image Network Provider is not loading images in (release mode app)real build app.(but loading images only in emulator)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So I am using cached_network_image: ^2.0.0 for the cached network image provider for my app.
So when I run the app on emulator and with connecting android phone with usb debugging, the Cached network image providor is working completely fine. All of the images are loaded properly.

But after building the apk version(release mode) and then when I install the app on android phone, then the cached network image providor is not loading the images. Only the white background is visible.

I had also done the Flutter clean and upgrading the cached_network_image :^3.0.0 then the problem was same.

Also when I use NetworkImage for the images, then the images were loading properly. But I want to cached the images to increase speed of the app.

So does anyone have idea that why the cached network image provider is working completely fine with usb debugging and not working after installing the build app-release.apk.

My code:-

```
leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.url)),//NetworkImage(user.url)
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes I had done it. Also I deleted the build with flutter clean and then again rebuild the app, then also the problem still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've found a workaround.
Add this to your android/app/build.gradle file:

```
    android {
   ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

[answer link](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/441#issuecomment-785473476)

Answer (score 6):

You may need to add internet permissions in the Android manifest (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: I had already done it before. This dosen't work. Still the images are not loading with cached image network provider.

Comment: I had also done flutter clean and then build again. Then also it  is not working.